# Disable Gyroscope/Device Orientation reading in VRView for web

Tags: javascript, html, webvr

I have a web application used for virtual house tours. Currently I am using VRView for these tours and it has worked pretty good, however I’ve ran in to an issue with the gyroscope that I need fixed as soon as possible.

VRView will automatically rotate the camera based on a users device orientation. As a user turns their phone, the virtual house tour will also turn, so the user is able to “look around” the house. This is great for most use cases, however lower end devices have issues when processing this sort of change. I need a way for users to disable the automatic rotation, and simply swipe on their phones to look around.

I’ve tried the permissions api and trying to revoke access to gyroscope, but due to browser compatibility with that api, it doesn’t work. I also can’t find any documentation on this in the VRView library. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;**

You're right, this doesn't seem to be available via their API.  It looks like you may have to fork the library and make some adjustments.  If you want to go down this path, I'd suggest forking the repo, seeing if you can successfully disable the motion emitter, and then see if you can use the webvr-polyfill to initiate drag controls.  It may also be possible to just disable the gyro-based rotation via webvr-polyfill directly.

**More in-depth explanation:**

The motion information is being published to the VR View iframes (which I believe then feed them to the webvr-polyfill controls) in two locations:
https://github.com/googlearchive/vrview/blob/bd12336b97eccd4adc9e877971c1a7da56df7d69/scripts/js/device-motion-sender.js#L35
https://github.com/googlearchive/vrview/blob/bd12336b97eccd4adc9e877971c1a7da56df7d69/src/api/iframe-message-sender.js#L45

When a browser's UA (user agent) flag indicates it can't use gyro controls, you would need to include a flag in that disables this functionality (or disables the listener in the iframe).

Normally, to enable drag rotation, I think you would then need to write a listener for the start and end of drag events that would translate those events into camera rotation. (Something similar to what this person is suggesting: https://github.com/googlearchive/vrview/issues/131#issuecomment-289522607)

However, it appears that the controls are imported via web-vr-polyfill. The 'window.WebVRConfig' object is coming from web-vr-polyfill, if I'm following this correctly.
See here: https://github.com/googlearchive/vrview/blob/bd12336b97eccd4adc9e877971c1a7da56df7d69/src/embed/main.js#L77

The code above looks like VR View is adjusting the WebVRConfig when it detects a certain flag (in this case the 'YAW_ONLY' attribute).  I believe you would have to do something similar.

https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill

See here for the YAW_ONLY attribute: https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill/blob/e2958490653bfcda4df83881d554bcdb641cf45b/src/webvr-polyfill.js#L68

See here for an example adjusting controls in webvr-polyfill:
https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill#using

Comment: That’s some great info! I’ll take a look in to some of these and see if I can find some sort of work around. Thank you for these. I was hoping to not have to fork it and just do a drop in JavaScript script, but it looks like it may not be that simple.

Comment: Awesome, let me know how it goes!